# How to generate a fixed random number in swift

Tags: swift

I want to generate a random color for my object, the same object keeps the same color.

The code now generates unpredictable random numbers every time

```
Color(
   red: Double.random(in: 0...1),
   green: Double.random(in: 0...1),
   blue: Double.random(in: 0...1)
)
```

Comment: you will need to store the rest somewhere and then reuse it, if you do it like this every time you call it its going to have a different value, you need to save the Color object once its been created with random values

Comment: "fixed random number" is an oxymoron. If it's fixed, it's not random. As `AngryDuck` said: you need this color to be a persisted property of an object, that's generated once and then reused for the lifetime of the object. This would also be a good time to remember that SwiftUI view structs are ephemeral descriptions of the views, not the views themselves.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution. You can create a UIColor object and store it the same way you would store anything else.

```
let fixedRandomColor = UIColor(red: Double.random(in: 0...255)/255, green: Double.random(in: 0...255)/255, blue: Double.random(in: 0...255)/255, alpha: 1)
```

Use `fixedRandomColor` wherever you want